# Why does the URL contain query strings ? How to remove these

Tags: userfrosting

Dear Userfrosting experts...

I have just installed Userfrosting on LAMP Stack. Ubutnu 16.04

The URL contains query strings : `http://example.com/dashboard#&sort[table-activities][occurred_at]=desc&page[table-activities]=1&size[table-activities]=10`

How can I get rid of these query strinngs ?

They look ugly !

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the [TableSorter sort2hash plugin](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sort-to-hash.html). The query strings are used to reapply the same sort and filter params if the page is accessed again.

It is enabled in [uf-table](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/d312d1f054c11d4bec011935042f154a0ec63003/app/sprinkles/core/assets/userfrosting/js/uf-table.js#L115). See USerFrosting document about Tables here : https://learn.userfrosting.com/4.2/client-side-code/components/tables

Comment: Thanks Louis ... but how do I remove it ?
I dont want these URL parameters in the URL string

Comment: There's no on/off switch as this is a feature. You'll need to overwrite the default `uf-table` config for each table. For example in https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/d312d1f054c11d4bec011935042f154a0ec63003/app/sprinkles/admin/assets/userfrosting/js/pages/dashboard.js#L35-L38


`activities.ufTable({
    dataUrl: site.uri.public + "/api/activities",
    useLoadingTransition: site.uf_table.use_loading_transition,
    widgets: ['saveSort', 'filter', 'pager', 'columnSelector', 'reflow2'],
});`